# Excel webpart limitations...?

Tags: web-part, error, excel-services

Excel webpart limitations?

Wanted to configure 8 Excel webparts on my SharePoint 2010 page, it works for 5-6 Excel webpart on the page and started throwing the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you provide the error message? It could be found in the Windows Event Log.

Comment: do not see any errors in the event log on the client machine?

Comment: @Karthikeyan the errors would be on the SharePoint server, not the client.